# How Can I Convert a Multidimensional Array in Php to XML

Tags: php, xml, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like

```
$a = array(
    'aaa' => "sample",
    'bbb' => "sample2",
    'ccc' => "adas",
    'ddd' => "2",
    'eee' => '2013-09-05',
    'fff' => "false",
    'ggg' => "893",
    'qqq' => '2013-09-05',
    'sss' => array(
        "iii" => array(
            'vvv' => "sample3",
            'xxx' => 500,
        )
    ),
    'nnn' => '2013-09-05',
    'mmm' => "Normal",
);
```

and I want to convert it to xml  but witout using SimpleXMLElement or another function. That's why I have tried to do it with foreach. Here is my code ;

```
$data = '';
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {

    if (is_array($k)) {
        $data .= "<a:$k>" . $v . "</a:$k>";
        foreach ($k as $j => $m) {
            if (is_array($j)) {
                foreach ($j as $s => $p) {
                    $data .= "<a:$s>" . $p . "</a:$s>";
                }
            } else {
                $data .= "<a:$j>" . $m . "</a:$j>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $data .= "<a:$k>" . $v . "</a:$k>";
    }
}
```

but it's not working. I can make it work with hashmaps in another language but it must be in php. How can I do this.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use recursion

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert array to SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

Comment: @BORA S.A. I know but I'll not use this function. Because I have another controls before it's convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
function createXml($array, $level = 0)
{
  $xml = ($level == 0) ? '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>'.PHP_EOL : '';
  $tab = str_pad('', $level, '  ', STR_PAD_LEFT);

  foreach($array as $node => $value)
  {
    $xml .= "{$tab}<{$node}>";
    if(!is_array($value))
    {
      $xml .= $value;
    }
    else
    {
      $level++;
      $xml .= PHP_EOL.createXml($value, $level).$tab;
    }
    $xml .= "</{$node}>".PHP_EOL;
  }
  return $xml;
}

$xml = createXml($a);
echo $xml;
```

Comment: first one tanks for answers. I fixed my problem.and here is the code `code` function createXml($x) {
    $r = '';
    foreach ($x as $key => $value) :
        $r .= (is_array($value)) ? "<$key>" . foreach_x($value) . "</$key>" : "<$key>$value</$key>";
    endforeach;
    return $r;
} `code`

Comment: Your function will not work on arrays with more than 2 dimensions. Also there is no arbitrary function called 'foreach_x'. If this is a function you have created then why create two functions where one would suffice? Did you try the function suggested?

Comment: yes i have try it and its work. and I have try it with 3 dimensions. I forget to change foreach_x to createXml.